# set json object custom listview

Tags: android, arrays, json

hello everyone I have a problem , I would set value to customlisview from jsonobject inside jsonarray . I made but , I getting only data  for the LoadList jsonarray, I didnt multiple jsonarray data.   How can I make  for the problem ?  My jsonobject data is here 
`

```
 {
 "PositionId": "574c1ccd02182121008b1980",
    "PositionRefNo": "00353","PositionInformation": {
    "LastActionTypeItem": null,
    "LastActionTime": null,
    "UseableActionTypes": [{
        "ActionType": "StartPosition",
        "ActionTypeDisplay": "Start"
    }],
     "LoadList": [{
            "Id": "5714ef197283771ac820269f",
            "OrderDate": "2016-04-18T17:25:00+03:00",
            "RefNo": "00265",
            "StatusName": "bla bla",
            "BranchName": "xxxxx",
            "ArrivalBranchName": "aaaaaa",
            "DepartureCityName": "bbbbb",
            "DepartureCountyName": "",
            "ArrivalCityName": "",
            "ArrivalCountyName": "",
            "OrderContent": "10 ",
            "UnloadingCustomerAddressType": "Warehouse"
        }, {
            "Id": "5714f761728377367414db0b",
            "OrderDate": "2016-04-18T18:02:00+03:00",
            "RefNo": "00266",
            "StatusName": "",
            "BranchName": "",
            "ArrivalBranchName": "",
            "DepartureCityName": "",
            "DepartureCountyName": "",
            "ArrivalCityName": "",
            "ArrivalCountyName": "",
            "OrderContent": "4 Palet",
            "UnloadingCustomerAddressType": "Warehouse"
        }, {
            "Id": "5716432372837636548073ae",
            "OrderDate": "2016-04-19T17:39:00+03:00",
            "RefNo": "00266-001",
            "StatusName": "",
            "BranchName": "",
            "ArrivalBranchName": "",
            "DepartureCityName": "",
            "DepartureCountyName": "",
            "ArrivalCityName": "",
            "ArrivalCountyName": "",
            "OrderContent": "1 Piece",
            "UnloadingCustomerAddressType": "www"
        }, {
            "Id": "571641967507d650b49c805a",
            "OrderDate": "2016-04-19T16:51:00+03:00",
            "RefNo": "00268",
            "StatusName": "cc",
            "BranchName": "dd",
            "ArrivalBranchName": "ee",
            "DepartureCityName": "ff",
            "DepartureCountyName": "gg",
            "ArrivalCityName": "g",
            "ArrivalCountyName": "",
            "OrderContent": "10 Palet",
            "UnloadingCustomerAddressType": ""
        }],
        "Status": true,
        "Message": "",                     
    }
}
```

`and my android model

```
   public class DomMobileLoadList {

    private String PositionId;
    private String PositionRefNo;
    private String Message;
    private Boolean Status;
    private ArrayList<LoadList> LoadList;
    private ArrayList<PositionInformation> PositionInformation;


    public DomMobileLoadList(JSONObject jObj) throws JSONException
    {
        this.PositionId = jObj.isNull("PositionId") || jObj.getString("PositionId").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("PositionId");
        this.PositionRefNo = jObj.isNull("PositionRefNo") || jObj.getString("PositionRefNo").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("PositionRefNo");
        this.Message = jObj.isNull("Message") || jObj.getString("Message").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("Message");
        this.Status = jObj.optBoolean("Status");

        if(!jObj.isNull("LoadList"))
        {           
            /*
            JSONObject jsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("LoadList");
            this.LoadList = new ArrayList<LoadList>();          
            this.LoadList.add(new LoadList(jsonObject));
            */
            this.LoadList = new ArrayList<LoadList>();
            JSONArray array = jObj.getJSONArray("LoadList");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
            {
                 this.LoadList.add(new LoadList(array.getJSONObject(i)));
            }

        }
        if(!jObj.isNull("PositionInformation"))
        {

            JSONObject jobposInfo = jObj.getJSONObject("PositionInformation");
            this.PositionInformation = new ArrayList<PositionInformation>();
            this.PositionInformation.add(new PositionInformation(jobposInfo));          

        }
    }





    public String getPositionId() {
        return PositionId;
    }

    public void setPositionId(String positionId) {
        PositionId = positionId;
    }

    public String getPositionRefNo() {
        return PositionRefNo;
    }

    public void setPositionRefNo(String positionRefNo) {
        PositionRefNo = positionRefNo;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Message = message;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public ArrayList<LoadList> getLoadList() {
        return LoadList;
    }

    public void setLoadList(ArrayList<LoadList> loadList) {
        LoadList = loadList;
    }

}
```

Finally my BaseAdapter Code here is

```
  public class DomMobileLoadListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

    // LoadList  vardı DomMobileLoadList olarak değiştirdim .
    Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<DomMobileLoadList> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public DomMobileLoadListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<DomMobileLoadList> items) {
        this.activity =  activity;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }    


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public DomMobileLoadList getLast()
    {
        return this.items.get(getCount()-1); 
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

     public void insertItem(int index, DomMobileLoadList item)
        {
            this.items.add(index, item);
        }

        public void addItem(DomMobileLoadList item)
        {
            this.items.add(item);
        }

        public ArrayList<DomMobileLoadList> getItems()
        {
            return this.items;
        }

        public void removeItem(int position)
        {
            this.items.remove(position);
        }

        public void removeItem(LoadList item)
        {
            this.items.remove(item);
        }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final DomMobileLoadList item = items.get(position);

               if(convertView == null)   
               vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dom_position_details, null);
               TextView txt_departurecityname=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.departure_city_name);
                TextView txt_departurecountyname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.departure_countname);
                TextView txt_arrivalcityname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.arrival_cityname);
                TextView txt_arrivalcountyname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.arrival_countname);
                TextView txt_branchname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_antrepo);
                TextView txt_ordercontent = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_ordercontent);
                TextView txt_unloadingcustomeraddresstype =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_unloadingcustomeraddresstype);

                /*
                txt_departurecityname.setText(item.getDepartureCityName());
                txt_departurecountyname.setText(item.getDepartureCountyName());
                txt_arrivalcityname.setText(item.getArrivalCityName());
                txt_arrivalcountyname.setText(item.getArrivalCountyName());
                txt_branchname.setText(item.getBranchName());           
                txt_ordercontent.setText(item.getOrderContent());
                txt_unloadingcustomeraddresstype.setText(item.getUnloadingCustomerAddressType());
                */
                for (int i = 0; i < item.getLoadList().size(); i++) {

                    txt_arrivalcityname.setText(item.getLoadList().get(i).getArrivalCityName());
                    txt_departurecountyname.setText(item.getLoadList().get(i).getDepartureCountyName());
                    txt_arrivalcityname.setText((item.getLoadList().get(i).getArrivalCityName()));
                    txt_arrivalcountyname.setText((item.getLoadList().get(i).getArrivalCountyName()));
                    txt_branchname.setText((item.getLoadList().get(i).getBranchName()));            
                    txt_ordercontent.setText((item.getLoadList().get(i).getOrderContent()));
                    txt_unloadingcustomeraddresstype.setText((item.getLoadList().get(i).getUnloadingCustomerAddressType()));


                }

                return vi;
    }

}
```

my LoadList class

```
    public LoadList(JSONObject jObj) throws JSONException
    {
        this.Id = jObj.isNull("Id") || jObj.getString("Id").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("Id");
        this.OrderDate = jObj.isNull("OrderDate") || jObj.getString("OrderDate").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("OrderDate");
        this.RefNo = jObj.isNull("RefNo") || jObj.getString("RefNo").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("RefNo");
        this.StatusName = jObj.isNull("StatusName") || jObj.getString("StatusName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("StatusName");
        this.BranchName = jObj.isNull("BranchName") || jObj.getString("BranchName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("BranchName");
        this.ArrivalBranchName = jObj.isNull("ArrivalBranchName") || jObj.getString("ArrivalBranchName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("ArrivalBranchName");
        this.DepartureCityName = jObj.isNull("DepartureCityName") || jObj.getString("DepartureCityName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("DepartureCityName");
        this.DepartureCountyName = jObj.isNull("DepartureCountyName") || jObj.getString("DepartureCountyName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("DepartureCountyName");
        this.ArrivalCityName = jObj.isNull("ArrivalCityName") || jObj.getString("ArrivalCityName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("ArrivalCityName");
        this.ArrivalCountyName = jObj.isNull("ArrivalCountyName") || jObj.getString("ArrivalCountyName").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("ArrivalCountyName");
        this.OrderContent = jObj.isNull("OrderContent") || jObj.getString("OrderContent").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("OrderContent");
        this.UnloadingCustomerAddressType = jObj.isNull("UnloadingCustomerAddressType") || jObj.getString("UnloadingCustomerAddressType").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("UnloadingCustomerAddressType");

    }


    public LoadList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getOrderDate() {
        return OrderDate;
    }
    public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
        OrderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public String getStatusName() {
        return StatusName;
    }
    public void setStatusName(String statusName) {
        StatusName = statusName;
    }
    public String getBranchName() {
        return BranchName;
    }
    public void setBranchName(String branchName) {
        BranchName = branchName;
    }
    public String getArrivalBranchName() {
        return ArrivalBranchName;
    }
    public void setArrivalBranchName(String arrivalBranchName) {
        ArrivalBranchName = arrivalBranchName;
    }
    public String getDepartureCityName() {
        return DepartureCityName;
    }
    public void setDepartureCityName(String departureCityName) {
        DepartureCityName = departureCityName;
    }
    public String getDepartureCountyName() {
        return DepartureCountyName;
    }
    public void setDepartureCountyName(String departureCountyName) {
        DepartureCountyName = departureCountyName;
    }
    public String getArrivalCityName() {
        return ArrivalCityName;
    }
    public void setArrivalCityName(String arrivalCityName) {
        ArrivalCityName = arrivalCityName;
    }
    public String getArrivalCountyName() {
        return ArrivalCountyName;
    }
    public void setArrivalCountyName(String arrivalCountyName) {
        ArrivalCountyName = arrivalCountyName;
    }
    public String getOrderContent() {
        return OrderContent;
    }
    public void setOrderContent(String orderContent) {
        OrderContent = orderContent;
    }

    public String getRefNo() {
        return RefNo;
    }

    public void setRefNo(String refNo) {
        RefNo = refNo;
    }

    public String getPositionRefNo() {
        return PositionRefNo;
    }

    public void setPositionRefNo(String positionRefNo) {
        PositionRefNo = positionRefNo;
    }

    public String getUnloadingCustomerAddressType() {
        return UnloadingCustomerAddressType;
    }

    public void setUnloadingCustomerAddressType(
            String unloadingCustomerAddressType) {
        UnloadingCustomerAddressType = unloadingCustomerAddressType;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is error log?

Comment: I havent error log I got data only one item. I would multiple data  set on the customlisview

Comment: are you unable to fetch other items from loadlist array right?

Comment: "Status": true,
        "Message": "",    

replace it by

 "Status": true,
        "Message": ""

Comment: this.LoadList.add(new LoadList(array.getJSONObject(i))); here you passing data to load list LoadList but where is the class??

Comment: public LoadList(JSONObject jObj) throws JSONException
 {
  this.Id = jObj.isNull("Id") || jObj.getString("Id").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("Id");
  this.OrderDate = jObj.isNull("OrderDate") || jObj.getString("OrderDate").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("OrderDate");
  this.RefNo = jObj.isNull("RefNo") || jObj.getString("RefNo").equals("null") ? "" :  jObj.optString("RefNo");
  this.StatusName = jObj.isNull("StatusName") || jObj.getString("StatusName").equals("null") ? "" :

Answer (score 0):

in the adapter, you have to inflate xml file and fill it with the current position data from the list as following:

```
     txt_arrivalcityname.setText(items.get(position).getArrivalCityName());

     txt_departurecountyname.setText(items.get(position).getDepartureCountyName());

     txt_arrivalcityname.setText((items.get(position).getArrivalCityName()));

     txt_arrivalcountyname.setText((items.get(position).getArrivalCountyName()));

     txt_branchname.setText((items.get(position).getBranchName()));            

     txt_ordercontent.setText((items.get(position).getOrderContent()));

     txt_unloadingcustomeraddresstype.setText((items.get(position).getUnloadingCustomerAddressType()));
```

Comment: for example my  getArrivalCityName();   doesnt DomLoadList class . İt has a another page in getLoadList()

Comment: but as your code, the method getLoadList() returns list of objects, so in which object is your arraivalCityName ??